# Feeding a value for placeholder tensor in Tensorflow C++ API

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have retrained Inception-v3 model using (Tensorflow) Python API and saved a standalone Graph in .pb by modifying tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py with the following modification to add a drop out layer before the classification layer:

```
def nn_layer(input_tensor, input_dim, output_dim, layer_name, activation_name='activation', act=tf.nn.softmax):
# Adding a name scope ensures logical grouping of the layers in the graph.
with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
# This Variable will hold the state of the weights for the layer
with tf.name_scope('weights'):
weights = weight_variable([input_dim, output_dim])
variable_summaries(weights, layer_name + '/weights')
with tf.name_scope('dropout'):
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
tf.scalar_summary('dropout_keep_probability', keep_prob)
drop = tf.nn.dropout(input_tensor, keep_prob)
variable_summaries(drop, layer_name + '/dropout')
with tf.name_scope('biases'):
biases = bias_variable([output_dim])
variable_summaries(biases, layer_name + '/biases')
preactivate = tf.matmul(drop, weights) + biases
tf.histogram_summary(layer_name + '/pre_activations', preactivate)
with tf.name_scope(activation_name):
activations = act(preactivate)
tf.histogram_summary(layer_name + '/activations', activations)
return preactivate, activations, keep_prob
```

The code to generate predictions in python is as follows:

```
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_layer/final_result/Softmax:0')
predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, { 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0':image_data, 'final_layer/dropout/Placeholder:0': 1.})
```

The C++ counterpart of the python code is as follows:

```
string input_layer = "Mul";
string output_layer = "final_layer/dropout/Placeholder:0";
Status run_status = session->Run({{input_layer, resized_tensor}}, {output_layer}, {}, &outputs);
```

The C++ code ends up with the following error message:

```
Running model failed: Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'final_layer/dropout/Placeholder'
```

What should I change in the above C++ code to remove this error? In other words, how do I change a placeholder value in the C++ code as in python code. I am stuck in this problem since many days. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C++ code is not the counterpart of your Python code.

In python you got

```
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_layer/final_result/Softmax:0')
predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, { 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0':image_data, 'final_layer/dropout/Placeholder:0': 1.})
```

Thus, your `feed_dict` is `{ 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0':image_data, 'final_layer/dropout/Placeholder:0': 1.}`.

that means: override the value of `DecodeJpeg/contents:0` with `image_data` and override the value of `final_layer/dropout/Placeholder:0` with `1.`.

In C++, instead, you got:

```
Status run_status = session->Run({{input_layer, resized_tensor}}, {output_layer}, {}, &outputs);
```

This, your `feed_dict` equivalent is the first input parameter, that is:

```
{{input_layer, resized_tensor}}
```

That means: override `input_layer` with `resized_tensor`.

The first problem is that you're trying overriding the node `Mul` and not node `DecodeJpeg/contents:0` as above.

Moreover, is missing the overriding of the placeholder.

However, there's some mess in your C++ code, because you called `output_tensor` what in fact is the `placeholder`.

## TL;DR

The counterpart if your Python code, should be something like

```
Status run_status = session->Run({
    {"DecodeJpeg/contents", resized_tensor},
    {"final_layer/dropout/Placeholder", 1f}
}, {"final_layer/final_result/Softmax"}, {}, &outputs);
```

that means:

override the node value of `DecodeJpeg/contents` with `resize_tensor`.
override the node value of `final_layer/dropout/Placeholder` with 1.

fetch the value of the node `final_layer/final_result/Softmax`.
put the results into `outputs`